# Prove that origin is globally exponentially stable with Lyapunov Indirect Method

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

I'm wondering, if we have a nonlinear system governed by

$\dot{x} = Ax + g(x)$ where $||g(x)|| \leq \gamma ||x||^2$ and A is Hurwitz

how can we show that the origin is globally exponentially stable? My first thoughts are to use Lyapunov's Indirect Method but what Lyapunov candidate function would work here?

Is $V(x) = x^{T}Px + \int_0^x g(y)dy$ suitable?

Or how else can we show that the origin is globally exponentially stable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just added the tags you specified

Comment: Why are you so sure that your claim is true, if you don't know a proof?